# MIN() OVER PARTITION resulting in duplicate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, amazon-redshift

I have a table that looks like:

| consumer_id | product_id | prod_state | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | wholesale | 1 |
| a | 1 | stock | 2 |
| a | 1 | sold | 3 |
| a | 1 | return | 4 |

I want to transform it such that my states are in the columns, and the value is the date, i.e something like

| consumer_id | product_id | wholesale_date | stock_date | sold_date | return_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |

(the dates are actual dates, but to create the table easily, I've just put numbers).

So in order to do this, I write the following code

```
SELECT consumer_id
     , product_id
     , CASE WHEN prod_state = 'wholesale'
          THEN MIN(date) OVER(PARTITION BY consumer_id, product_id, prod_state)
          ELSE NULL 
     END as wholesale_date
     , CASE WHEN prod_state = 'stock'
          THEN MIN(date) OVER(PARTITION BY consumer_id, product_id, prod_state)
          ELSE NULL 
     END as sold_date
     , CASE WHEN prod_state = 'wholesale'
          THEN MIN(date) OVER(PARTITION BY consumer_id, product_id, prod_state)
          ELSE NULL 
       END as sold_date

from table
```

With a similar case statement used for each state.

However what this ends up doing is creating a table that looks a bit like this

| consumer_id | product_id | wholesale_date | stock_date | sold_date | return_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 1 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| a | 1 | NULL | 2 | NULL | NULL |
| a | 1 | NULL | NULL | 3 | NULL |
| a | 1 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 4 |

How do I remove all the duplicate rows and collapse them all into one row?

Even by adding group by's to the bottom of my query doesn't help with this.

Thank you

Comment: Don't use a windowed aggregate, use a non-windowed aggregate and a `GROUP BY`. There aren't "duplicate rows", you have 1 row per row in your table.

Comment: Can't debug a query **fragment**

Comment: @Larnu So i changed my case statement to read CASE WHEN state = x THEN MIN(date) ELSE NULL and grouped by 1,2,state and I still get the multiple rows

Comment: `GROUP BY` doesn't accept ordinal positions in SQL Server, @c_n_blue ; I would expect an error. Though your aggregate should be wrapped around the entire `CASE` expression, and you shouldn't be grouping on it.

Comment: OHHH, so to read MIN (CASE ) . GReat, did this and it worked. Thank you

Comment: @c_n_blue Would you mind posting the working code as an answer? It's OK on Stack Overflow to answer your own question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server)